# Problems with my code after converting from Visual studio 2013 to Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project that is working correctly on Visual studio 2013 Ultimate.
Now we have installed Visual studio 2017 Enterprise.
When I compile and run my project on VS2017 , on several lines of code I receive a strange error message :

```
"Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not
 available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away."
```

What can I do  , because on VS2013 I had no problems at all.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

uncheck in the project "optimize code"

Also, set the debug info dropdown to full in the advanced options

go to Debug->Options or Tools->Options

and check Debugging->General->Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed only)

if you would like a technical reason, you need to post your code

Comment: I can't find "Optimize code" on VS 2017.Where is it ?

Comment: right click the project and go to properties (not the solution), then click on the build tab

Comment: There's no Buld TAB on Project-Properties. ( I'm using VS 2017 Enterprise ).